# tmux session name in terminal window

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, zsh, tmux, tmuxinator

I often run two tmux sessions in separate Terminal.app tabs. I used named sessions through tmuxinator. I would like a way to show that session name as the title of the tab, so I can identify which tmux session is which.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Looking at the tmuxinator documentation (http://rubydoc.info/gems/tmuxinator/0.5.0/frames) I don't see a way to promote the session name to the console application (Terminal or iTerm2 or whatever).

There are a couple of alternative tools like tmuxinator:

tmuxstart: https://github.com/treyhunner/tmuxstart
teamocil: https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil

Neither of these appear to offer the ability to promote the session name to the tab title either.

I'm not sure you can do what you want.

Comment: @MarkNichols Thanks. I'm wondering, might tmux handle this natively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible using tmux configuration

> set-titles [on | off ] Attempt to set the window title using the
> \e]2;...\007 xterm code if the terminal appears to be an xterm. This
> option is off by default. Note that elinks will only attempt to set
> the window title if the STY environment variable is set.
>
> set-titles-string string String used to set the window title if
> set-titles is on. Character sequences are replaced as for the
> status-left option.

The item in question is `#S Ta Session name`.

Check the man page.

To set this for a the session currently connected/active:

```
$ tmux set-option -s set-titles on
$ tmux set-option -s set-titles-string '#S'
```